# javascript objects sharing data unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, object, instantiation

I'm working on a map application, and I need to link different events to different types of markers. The createMarkers function creates a few markers by random, but their overlay events always say exactly the same though their colors are different. This is built on Leaflet.js

```
    function createMarkers() {
            for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
                var color, kind;
                switch(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)) {
                    case 0:
                        color = greenFlag;
                        kind = "film";
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        color = redFlag;
                        kind = "music";
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        color = blueFlag;
                        kind = "images";
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        color = yellowFlag;
                        kind = "text";
                    break;
                    default:
                }
                var lat = Math.random() * 3 - 75;
                var lng = Math.random() * 3 - 112;
                var marker = L.marker([lat, lng], {icon: color}).addTo(map).on('click', function() {
                    overlay(kind);
                });
            }
        }

    function overlay(kind) {
            alert(kind);
        }
```

All the markers created have the same value when clicked, e.g. "film". I've tried storing the overlay(kind) in a variable inside the first switch statement and calling that. I've also tried creating a second switch statement in the marker.on('click') function but neither of these has solved the problem. I feel like I'm missing something pretty key about javascript/objects here.

Thank you!

Comment: What is L ? is it (unintentionally) a global obect?

Comment: L is for the Leaflet.js object, its intentionally global.  http://leafletjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a closure so the scope of the outer function is retained.

```
function createMarkers() {

        for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            var color, kind;
            switch(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)) {
                case 0:
                    color = greenFlag;
                    kind = "film";
                break;
                case 1:
                    color = redFlag;
                    kind = "music";
                break;
                case 2:
                    color = blueFlag;
                    kind = "images";
                break;
                case 3:
                    color = yellowFlag;
                    kind = "text";
                break;
                default:
            }
            var lat = Math.random() * 3 - 75;
            var lng = Math.random() * 3 - 112;
            var marker = L.marker([lat, lng], {icon: color}).addTo(map).on('click',overlay(kind));
        }
    }

function overlay(kind) {
  return function(){
        alert(kind);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never really seen this concept before- it's really cool!

Comment: I think I understand why this works: by overlay() returning a function it encapsulates that function such that it won't be overwritten by the instantiation of newer markers. But I don't understand why/how new markers created in the for loop could know anything about their sibling instantiations, much less affect their onclick event. Maybe you could shed some light?

Comment: They didn't, they knew about `i` which after the loop was ran was set to 10.

Comment: This is the best explanation of closures I have found: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/  I read this about once a year, its a long read but well worth it.

Comment: haha, I stared at your response (which is very poetic at this time of night:) deciding whether to keep asking questions. thanks for coming back with this- i'm sure it will be an eye opener